# Slick SLider - как скрыть стрелки если нет слайдов

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js, slider-slick.js

Подскажите пожалуйста!
1. Как скрыть стрелки у slick slider если слайд 1
2. Как сделать количество dots равным количеству слайдов?

Спасибо.

Думаю нет смысла прикреплять код, так как задача вполне тривиальная, но не могу найти решения.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы скрыть стрелки, в настройках слайдера в вашем js файле пропишите: `arrows: false`

Количество dots зависит от количества слайдов, которые вращаются за один раз, данное кол-во тоже можно задать в настройках: `slidesToScroll: 1`

Comment: Со стрелками разобрался - спасибо! Если у меня 1 слайд, то пропадает пагинация

Comment: $slick.slick({
        draggable: true,
        customPaging: function (slider, i) {
            var title = $(slider.$slides[i]).find('[data-title]').data('title');
            return '<a class="pager__item"> ' + title + ' </a>';
        },
        dots: true,
        mobileFirst: true,
        prevArrow: '<button id="prev" type="button" class="btn slick-custom-prev"></button>',
        nextArrow: '<button id="next" type="button" class="btn slick-custom-next"></button>',
    });

Comment: @Dianov Evgenii А зачем вам пагинация если у вас 1 слайд?

Comment: Дело в том, что заказчик должен иметь возможность добавлять слайды. Но пока там только 1 слайд и на нем пропадает пагинация.\

Comment: Так скрипт не срабатывает если слайдов мало, есть же такой параметр slidesPerView: 4,, если меньше чем тут, то и стрелок не будет и пагинации, ибо как бы листать нечего, этож логично.